# NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, exception, crash

I am receiving this error from a bug report and have no idea what has caused it.

Here is the complete error message:

```
Hardware Model:     [object Object]
Process:            SkippersLog
Identifier:         de.sioned.skipperslog
Version:            1.2.1
OS Version:         iOS 13.6.1



NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000

0  CoreFoundation          ___exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib         _objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation          -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
3  CoreFoundation          ____forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation          ___forwarding_prep_0___
5  SkippersLog             generic specialization <__C.CKRecordID, __C.CKRecord> of Swift.Dictionary._Variant.updateValue(_: __owned B, forKey: A) -> B? (<compiler-generated>)
6  SkippersLog             updateValue (<compiler-generated>)
7  SkippersLog             closure #1 () -> () in SkippersLog.CloudKitFactory.transferAllTablesToCloud() -> () (CloudKitFactory.swift:203:18)
8  SkippersLog             reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> () (<compiler-generated>)
9  libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_call_block_and_release
10 libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_client_callout
11 libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_root_queue_drain
12 libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_worker_thread2
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib __pthread_wqthread
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib _start_wqthread
```

The only cause can be the **updateRecords.updateValue(ckrecord, forKey: ckrecord.recordID)** call in the following function:

```
func gatherCachedRecords()
{
    var ckcaches  : [CKCache] = []
    
    *** filling ckcaches from database her ***

    updateRecords.removeAll()
  
    for ckcache in ckcaches
    {
        if let dbrecord = DBRecord.findDBRecord (recid:ckcache.recid)
        {
            let ckrecord = dbrecord.createCKRecord()
            updateRecords.updateValue(ckrecord, forKey: ckrecord.recordID)
        }
    } 
}
```

**updateRecords** is a property of the class defined as:

```
private var updateRecords    : [CKRecord.ID: CKRecord] = [:]
```

***gatherCachedRecords*** is called in global DispatchQueue:

```
func transferAllTablesToCloud()
{
    CKManager.shared.activityIndicator(on: true)
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async
    {
        self.dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        self.gatherCachedRecords()

        *** do some other stuff here ***
        
     }
}
```

**transferAllTablesToCloud** is only called once during startup of the app. The only possible problem I could guess is, that **updatedRecord** is declared on class scope and not locally within the DispatchQueue block, but I have no idea why this could be a problem.
This should only cause trouble if **transferAllTablesToCloud** would be called more than once and at the same time running concurrently.

The class that hosts all this is a singleton.

I cannot reproduce this in my development environment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to run this code on release configuration, release Optimization can give you different result

Comment: First, the address 0x8000000000000000 looks as if something strange happens. Maybe some race condition when accessing `updateRecords` from a different thread, or some memory issue. Quinn gives some hints: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/116028 Skippers greetings!

Comment: Thanks for the link, Andreas. It got me some ideas. I will try to make the whole process thread safe, just in case. It _should_ not be run more than once at the same time, but one never knows...